# Download and extract a tar file in Python in chunks

Tags: python

I am trying to use `pycurl` to download a tgz file and extract it using `tarfile`, but without storing the tgz file on disk and by not having the whole tgz file in memory. I would like to download it and extract it in chunks, streaming.

I know how to get pycurl callback which gives me data every time a new chunk of data is downloaded:

```
def write(data):
    # Give data to tarfile to extract.
    ...

with contextlib.closing(pycurl.Curl()) as curl:
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, tar_uri)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, write)
    curl.setopt(curl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
    curl.perform()
```

I also know how to open tarfile in streaming mode:

```
output_tar = tarfile.open(mode='r|gz', fileobj=fileobj)
```

But I do not know how to connect these two things together, so that every time I get a chunk over the wire, the next chunk of the tar file is extracted.

Comment: "download a tgz file and extract it (...), but without storing anything on disk and by not having the whole tgz file in memory" => Err, I'm not sure this is possible at all, actually.

Comment: I updated the language. But yea, it is possible. `curl tar_uri | tar -xz` does this outside of Python. How can I do it in Python?

Comment: Where have you seen that `curl tar_uri | tar -xz` doesn't store anything on disk or in memory ?

Comment: It does not store on the disk the tar file (it goes over the pipe to `tar` program). And yes, it stores a bit in memory while downloading it, but not the whole tar file.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It is definitely possible. Tar files don't have a central directory (they're basically just file records one after the other) and gzip can be decompressed as a stream.

Comment: Ok then, so it might be possible indeed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, unless you're *really* looking for a pure-Python solution (which is possible, just rather tedious), I would suggest to just shell out to `/usr/bin/tar` and feed it data in chunks.

Something like

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/tar', 'xz', '-C', '/my/output/directory'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

def write(data):
    p.stdin.write(data)

with ...:
    curl.perform()

p.close()
```

Comment: Yea, this is also what I was thinking as a workaround. It would work, but I was wondering how to do it in pure Python. In node I would just pipe things together, but in Python it seems this is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

A Python only solution could look like this:

```py
import contextlib
import tarfile
from http.client import HTTPSConnection


def https_download_tar(host, path, item_visitor, port=443, headers=dict({}), compression='gz'):
    """Download and unpack tar file on-the-fly and call item_visitor for each entry.

        item_visitor will receive the arguments TarFile (the currently extracted stream)
                       and the current TarInfo object
    """
    with contextlib.closing(HTTPSConnection(host=host, port=port)) as client:
        client.request('GET', path, headers=headers)
        with client.getresponse() as response:
            code = response.getcode()
            if code < 200 or code >= 300:
                raise Exception(f'HTTP error downloading tar: code: {code}')
            try:
                with tarfile.open(fileobj=response, mode=f'r|{compression}') as tar:
                    for tarinfo in tar:
                        item_visitor(tar, tarinfo)
            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception(f'Failed to extract tar stream: {e}')

# Test the download function using some popular archive
def list_entry(tar, tarinfo):
    print(f'{tarinfo.name}\t{"DIR" if tarinfo.isdir() else "FILE"}\t{tarinfo.size}\t{tarinfo.mtime}')

https_download_tar('dl.discordapp.net', '/apps/linux/0.0.15/discord-0.0.15.tar.gz', list_entry)
```

The `HTTPSConnection` is used to provide a response stream (file-like) which is then passed to `tarfile.open()`.

One can then iterate over the items in the TAR file and for example extract them using `TarFile.extractfile()`.

Comment: Thanks. I have moved away from pycurl in meantime so this applies now. But my original question was how to do it when using pycurl.